# Argument error while running Cucumber tests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I was following the Rails Testing handbook from semaphore and I encountered this issue while running the tests for `authentication_steps.rb`.

> wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

The test that gives the above error is below

```
When("I fill in the sign up form") do
    click_link "Sign up"
    fill_in "user_email", :with => "tester@testdomain.test"
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "pa$$word"
    fill_in "user_password_confirmation", :with => "pa$$word"
    click_button "Sign up"
end
```

Below is the image showing the errors. `capybara v3.0.2`, `cucumber v3.1.0`
[image]

Authentication is implemented using devise.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure there's more info, about for example which method call causes this error.

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot of the error messages. Kindly check it out @Marek Lipka

Comment: After doing some debugging, the error appears at the `click_link` and the `click_button` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Driver::Node#click` method changed in Capybara 3 to be able to support offset clicking and clicking with keys held down. Driver writers need to update their implementations to accept those parameters now. You don't identify which driver you're using but whatever version of whichever driver you're using isn't compatible with Capybara 3.x

In the future running Cucumber tests with the `--backtrace` option should give you a full stack trace on errors which would make it easier to debug issues.

Comment: You are right. Downgrading to Capybara 2.6.2 helped. Thanks